# State not updating with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I am trying to delete a post with Redux however the state is not updating when I do so, only when I reload the page I can then delete the Posts which then display.

Please see the `App.js` component here...

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PostForm from './PostForm';
import { getPosts, deletePost } from '../actions/actions';

class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount () {
    this.props.getPosts();
  }

  _getPostId(evt) {
    const postId = evt.target.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute('data-id');
    this.props.deletePost(postId)
  }

  render() {
    const posts = this.props.postsData.map( (index) => {
      return (
        <tr data-id={index._id}>
          <td> {index.title} </td>
          <td> {index.body} </td>
          <td> <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this._getPostId.bind(this)}>Delete</button> </td>
        </tr>
      )
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
          <div className="container">
            <a className="navbar-brand">Blog Admin</a>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div className="container">
          <PostForm />
          <table className="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Body</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {posts}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(state => state, { deletePost, getPosts })(App);
```

Please see my `reducers.js` file below...

```
export const postsData =  ( state = [], action ) => {
  switch ( action.type ) {
    case 'GET_POSTS':
      return state;
    case 'STORE_POSTS':
      return [...action.data]
    case 'ADD_POST':
      let newPost = {
        title: action.data.title,
        body: action.data.body
      }
      return state.concat( [newPost] )
    case 'DELETE_POST':
    let postId = action.data;
    return state.filter(p => p._id !== postId)
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Please the `actions.js` file below...

```
import store from '../store/store.js';

export function getPosts() {
  apiPostCall();
  return { type: 'GET_POSTS' };
}

export function addNewPost(post) {
  apiAddPost(post);
  return { type: 'ADD_POST', data: post }
}

export function deletePost(postId) {
  apiDeletePost(postId);
  return { type: 'DELETE_POST', data: postId }
}

function apiPostCall() {
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/api/posts",
    dataType: "json"
  }).success(data =>  store.dispatch({ type: 'STORE_POSTS', data }))
}

function apiAddPost(post) {
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/api/posts",
    data: post,
    dataType: "json"
  }).success()
}

function apiDeletePost(postId) {
  $.ajax({
    method: "DELETE",
    url: "/api/posts/" + postId,
  }).success();
}
```

Comment: should let postId = action.data actually be something like action.data._id? Since action.data is an object and not an id (action.data.body, action.data.title), according to the rest of your code?

Comment: Hi, In the `actions.js` file, I pass in the `id` into the data. I have included the file above also. Thanks

Comment: Is the call going correctly for deleting?
Also why are you doing `case 'STORE_POSTS':      return [...action.data]` ?

Comment: Actions should not modify your data. They should simply pass it along. Their purpose is to describe the fact that something happened. Reducers are in charge of modifications to that data.

Comment: Hi Abhinav, this action is dispatched on the success of the API call and then it returns the [...action.data] as in the reducer.

Comment: in _getPostId, try using .parentElement instead of .parentNode. Nodes don't have a getAttribute method. Also, do some logging of the data and try to narrow down where the problem actually is. It's hard to debug even a simple application like this since we don't have your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve this issue!

So after logging out some data I found out that when a post was added it did not include the `id` from the database, only when I reloaded the page the posts included the `id` because it calls the API.

So when a user adds a post via the form I then create an `id` which is posted to the API and then sent to the Redux store.

Also thank you for your suggestions, much appreciated.